# How to create a table of more than one value in column

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in python with multiple columns. I can create another list of a certain value in a specific column, but how do I do multiple values within the same column?

Here is my code to display the list for only RB:

```
NewTable=Football[Football.Position=='RB']
```

However I want RB and WR. How should I modify my code?

Comment: "table" isn't a basic Python datatype.  Do you have a pandas DataFrame, or a numpy ndarray, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First off i'll say that to make the code more pythonic you should ditch the CamelCase variables! Secondly the question is kind of hard to decipher, if I understand correctly then this should help...

```
new_table = football[ (football.position == 'RB') & (football.position == ''WR')]
```